# Не удаётся загрузить изображение на сервер из буфера обмена через fetch(electron)

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, fetch, electron

Получаю изображение из буфера обмена с помощью electron clipboard в формате [NativeImage](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/native-image) , далее пытаюсь его отправить с помощью FormData

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("image", image.toPNG());
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
}).then(response => {
    response.text().then(text => {
        win.webContents.send("result", {found: true, status: response.status, text: text});
                });
            });
```

Так получаю данные в python с помощью Sanic:

```
for filename, image in request.files.items():
   if image:
        async with AIOFile(f'{SKETCH_IMAGES}/{filename}', 'wb') as afp:
             await afp.write(image[0].body)
        sketch_id = ...
        return response.json({'id': sketch_id, 'filepath': filename})
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```